# How do I avoid IFERROR testing for empty arrays in FILTER function?

Tags: excel, excel-formula

I want to count the results of a FILTER in excel. Usually I do something like

```
IF(
    IFERROR(
            SUM(
                FILTER( range, condition)
            )
    , -1) <> -1,
    COUNTA(FILTER( range, condition)),
    0
)
```

Because if your filter returns with an empty array, it throws an error. When you do a COUNTA on it it will return 1... how do I prevent this without stating my filter function twice?

How do I get a counta of empty filter to return zero?

Comment: Okay let me try

Comment: @MayukhBhattacharya So I am having a hard time understanding how this will fix my issue. Because I am trying to get a count of values. But if I return something in the if empty my counta will be 1. Is there something I can place in there that counta won't pick up?

Comment: use LET: `=LET(f,FILTER(range, condition,-1),IF(SUM(f)<>-1,COUNTA(f),0))`

Comment: Try the one as suggested by @ScottCraner Sir.

Comment: Seems to work... except it is spilling now? I thought COUNTA is only supposed to return one value. I just summed the values and it seems to do a good job. Thanks @ScottCraner

Comment: Yes, I edited the comment to add the sum also.  If the filter returns more than one it will spill without it.

Comment: Do you have a small piece of sample data to show what it is you are trying. I'm trying to figure out why you not using `COUNTIF()` for example. Maybe even `REDUCE()` comes in handy.

Comment: Why not use `ROWS` in place of `COUNTA`? `=IFERROR(ROWS(FILTER(range,condition)),0)` Or `COLUMNS` if the range is horizontal.

Comment: There is possibility of blank rows. I need to ensure they are not counted

Comment: But then set the condition to exclude blank rows?